# C# Decimal to VB6 Currency

Tags: c#, vb6, interop, decimal, currency

I have one C# DLL and one Visual Basic 6 DLL.

In C# there is a field x with data type **Decimal**.
In VB6 there is a field y with data type **Currency**.

What would be the best way to pass x to y and back?

Currently I convert the fields to **Double**, but I am not sure if there are rounding implications.

*Update 1:*

Based on the helpful advice this is what my code looks now:

```
    public void FromVbToNet(long vb6curr)
    {
        decimal value = vb6curr / 10000;
    }
```

Problem is, when I try to call this from VB6 via interop, I get a compile error:

"Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic"

So how do I declare vb6curr? **String**, **Object**, **Dynamic**?

*Update 2:*

In case anyone needs this for reference, after further reading I came up with the following solution:

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Currency)]
public decimal GetDecimalFromNetDll()
{
    decimal value = ... // Read from database
    return value;
}

public void SetDecimalInNetDll([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Currency)] decimal value)
{
    // Save to database
}
```

I call these from my unmanaged code in VB6 with a **Currency** parameter and everything seems to work so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some reading I came up with this solution (see also under *Update 2*).

I had to marshal the **Decimal** type in .Net to the **Currency** type in the unmanaged VB6 code and vice versa.

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Currency)]
public decimal GetDecimalFromNetDll()
{
    decimal value = ... // Read from database
    return value;
} 

public void SetDecimalInNetDll([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Currency)] decimal value)
{
    // Save to database
}
```

For detailed information see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 9):

A VB6 `Currency` data type is stored as a 64 bit integer, implicitly scaled by `10,000`. Armed with that knowledge it is straightforward to convert between that type and .net `Decimal`.

On the VB6 side you pass the data as `Currency`. On the C# side you pass it as `long`. Then on the C# side you scale by `10,000` to convert between your `decimal` value and the `long` value.

For example when you have a VB6 `Currency` value held in a C# long you convert to `decimal` like this:

```
long vb6curr = ...;
decimal value = vb6curr / 10000;
```

In the other direction it would be:

```
decimal value = ...;
long vb6curr = Convert.ToInt64(value*10000);
```

Comment: Sorry I am really at a loss here. I have tried a long variable (int64), but that is not supported by VB6. The only solution I see is rounding the decimal to a double, since double is the only 64 bit type that VB6 knows. Am I correct?

Comment: On the VB6 side, use `Currency`. On the C# side use `long`. Scale the value by `10,000` in C# code when converting between `decimal` and `long`.